# Is there an issue with working directory when using service to launch an init script?

Tags: python, service, background-process, chkconfig

I am curious, is there something I need to watch out for when spawning process as background jobs from init scripts using `service`?

Here is the line that works at terminal, in a bash script/an init script, but will not successfully launch when using chkconfig: `service celerydsvcname start`

`/var/www/rhodecode-venv/bin/paster celeryd /var/www/rhodecode/production.ini --pidfile=/var/run/celeryd.pid -f /var/log/celerydpaster.log -l WARNING -q &`

Some interesting troubleshooting I've done:

```
cd /var/www/rhodecode-venv/bin
/var/www/rhodecode-venv/bin/paster celeryd /var/www/rhodecode/production.ini --pidfile=/var/run/celeryd.pid -f /var/log/celerydpaster.log -l WARNING -q &
sleep 2
ls -l /proc/$(pgrep paste)/cwd
echo Done.
```

I get the following returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/rhodecode-venv/bin/paster", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.4.2', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/var/www/rhodecode-venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.4.2-py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 103, in run
    command = commands[command_name].load()
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
  File "/var/www/rhodecode-venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/RhodeCode-1.2.2-py2.6.egg/rhodecode/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    _rev = get_current_revision(quiet=True)
  File "/var/www/rhodecode-venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/RhodeCode-1.2.2-py2.6.egg/rhodecode/lib/__init__.py", line 403, in get_current_revision
    except (ImportError, RepositoryError, VCSError), err:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'RepositoryError' referenced before assignment
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Oct 27 11:34 /proc/12265/cwd -> /var/www/rhodecode-venv/bin
Done.
```

The python error is logged because the working directory is incorrect; but it is reported as correct by `ls -l /proc/$(pgrep paste)/cwd`!

Again, note that `/var/www/rhodecode-venv/bin/paster celeryd /var/www/rhodecode/production.ini --pidfile=/var/run/celeryd.pid -f /var/log/celerydpaster.log -l WARNING -q &` runs without issue from the terminal and a bash script, or even if I execute the init script from the terminal.  It is only when I use `service celerydsvcname start` that I run into this working directory issue.

It doesn't matter whether or not the process is spawned (via `service`) in the foreground or background, the issue is persistent.

How is the process context changed when running using `service` to execute the init script?

Thanks!

Matt

[updated]

The script is referring to the HOME environmental variable for which. `service` starts the service as `env -i PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "/etc/init.d/celerydsvcname" start`, where `-i` ignores the current environment.  This means that I can't expect environmental variables to be present in the environment that's started with `service`, unless I set them.  Lesson learned.

Comment: I saw the undefine error with RepositoryError variable. Try to redirect both of stdout and stderr to a log file: `/var/www/rhodecode-venv/bin/paster ... -q > /tmp/paster.log 2>&1 &` to see what does it say.

Comment: Thanks.  I previously used `../paster ... -q &> logfile.log`.  But redirected both using your syntax as well and the only thing logged is the above error contents from python.  Also note I changed the question a bit to reflect that the fact that I'm spawning the process in the background is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: To note: it's not a python error.  The global variable is established when the code is called within the proper virtualenv, which is clearly the case from any of the working methods I've noted: from terminal/CLI, from another bash script, even running the init script itself.  **Only when using `service` does paste fail with this error.**

Comment: Post the output of `sh -x /etc/init.d/celerydsvcname start` and content of `/sbin/service`?

Comment: Thanks for following up quanta... see: http://pastebin.com/z5riDngR  Note that I can run the `/etc/init.d/celerydsvcname` within bash without a problem, it launches: http://pastebin.com/uhvbmvkx

Comment: You lack of `start`.

Comment: Sorry done: http://pastebin.com/uhvbmvkx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1666/discussion-between-mbrownnyc-and-quanta) if you'd like...

Comment: Change the "shelbang" of your init script to `#!/bin/sh -x` and show us the output of `sh -x /sbin/service paste-script-celeryd start`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved problem with rhodecode - init.d by adding

```
export HOME=/home/ak
```

to the `init.d` script.

Comment: This is obviously what I did, but it seem like quite a bad thing to do? I guess may be not since it's just an adjustment of the environment where the process is running.